# Google sheet JSON table feed, alter color of a row depending on value in cell

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-sheets

Breaking my head over this the last few days, have tried lots of options I found here but still no luck.

Did find the solution to get JSON feed to html page here ;-) Which is awesome!!!
As I´m pretty newbie to get this working was a revelation, man it felt good :)

Anyway, my question;

I have this javascript:

```
 var spreadsheetID = "1YUKom7FNEvxqSlQiSao_aLEcC0cLVyg5xmBv-JsaIUs";

 var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  var html = '';

  html += '<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100% id=table_id>';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td>Date</td>';
  html += '<td>Currency Pair</td>';
  html += '<td>Buy / Sell</td>';
  html += '<td>Stop-Loss</td>';
  html += '<td>Amount</td>';
  html += '<td>Price</td>';
  html += '<td>Closing Price</td>';
  html += '<td>P/L</td>';
  html += '<td>PIP</td>';
  html += '<td>P/L US$</td>';
  html += '<td>P/L EURO</td>';
  html += '<td>Entry Time</td>';
  html += '<td>Exit Time</td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  var entry = data.feed.entry;
  for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$date']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pair']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$bs']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$sl']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$amount']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$price']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$closeprice']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pl']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pip']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$plusd']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pleuro']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$entry']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$exit']['$t'] + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
      }
  html += '</table>';

  $('.console').html(html);
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>...</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="console"></div>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I am looking for is if a value in this row

```
html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pl']['$t'] + '</td>';
```

contains a value that has "-€" in it that the whole row turns red.

Thanks in advance if anyone out here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to put an condition around that specific line to check for the symbol.

```
if (entry[i]['gsx$pl']['$t'].indexOf("-€") !== -1) {
    // Has the symbol
    html += '<td style="background-color: #600;">' + entry[i]['gsx$pl']['$t'] + '</td>';
} else {
    // Doesn't have symbol
    html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pl']['$t'] + '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply :) So this bit goes right after this?  html += '<td>' + entry[i]['gsx$pl']['$t'] + '</td>';

Comment: Would replace, not go after